# How to access the keys of an indexed array

Tags: javascript

Say I have the array below, and I want to retrieve the keys inside the indexed object, so that I would end up with an array like this `["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop3"]`

```
const testArray =  [
    {
      0: {
        prop1: "sdsd", 
        prop2: "ssdsd"
      }
    },
    {
      1: {
        prop3: "sdsd", 
        prop4: "sddd"
      }
    }
 ]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce and concat:

```js
const testArray =  [
    {
      0: {
        prop1: "sdsd", 
        prop2: "ssdsd"
      }
    },
    {
      1: {
        prop3: "sdsd", 
        prop4: "sddd"
      }
    }
 ]

const keys = testArray.reduce((arr, curr, index) => 
                 arr.concat(Object.keys(curr[index])),[])

console.log(keys)
// ["prop1", "prop2", "prop3", "prop4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over the array, taking the value's keys

```js
const testArray =  [
    {
      0: {
        prop1: "sdsd", 
        prop2: "ssdsd"
      }
    },
    {
      1: {
        prop3: "sdsd", 
        prop4: "sddd"
      }
    }
 ]
 
 const keys = testArray
                .map(e => Object.keys(...Object.values(e)))
                .flat();
                
 console.log(keys);
```

---

Note that [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is experimental for now, so you might want to use reduce or so to flatten the array...

Answer (score 0):

@bambam has given the solution with "map", which is clearer. 
You can also do that with "reduce" as below.

```
testArray.reduce((arr, d) => 
            (arr.push(
                   Object.entries(d).map(([, l]) => Object.keys(l))
                   )
             , arr) 
            ,[]).flat(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution with forEach

```js
const testArray =  [
    {
      0: {
        prop1: "sdsd", 
        prop2: "ssdsd"
      }
    },
    {
      1: {
        prop3: "sdsd", 
        prop4: "sddd"
      }
    }
 ];
 
 var arr = [];
 
 testArray.forEach((data, index) => {
    let tempArr = Object.keys(data[index]);
    arr = arr.concat(tempArr);
 })
 
 console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const testArray =  [
    {
      0: {
        prop1: "sdsd", 
        prop2: "ssdsd"
      }
    },
    {
      1: {
        prop3: "sdsd", 
        prop4: "sddd"
      }
    }
 ];
var arr = testArray.map((p)=>{return Object.keys(p[Object.keys(p)[0]]);});
console.log([].concat.apply([],arr));
```